# SQL Server - Sum with conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to aggregate some columns, but there are some conditions. Please consider the following:

```
Encounter
number  enc_id
1324        01      

Charge
charge_id   enc_id  amt1    amt2    amt3
01          01      0.00    0.00    0.01
02          01      0.00    0.01    0.02

SELECT Encounter.number, sum(Charge.amt3)
    FROM Charge
    WHERE
        Charge.enc_id = '01'
    GROUP BY 
        Encounter.number
    HAVING
        sum(Charge.amt1 + Charge.amt2) = 0.00
```

The database rule is there are multiple charges in an encounter. I need to sum `amt3`, but if any of the charges have the following condition: `amt1`> 0.00  or `amt2` > 0.00 then do not sum any of the related charges.

This is what being returned

```
Enc_number  sum(Charge.amt3)
1234        0.01
```

I should not be returning anything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I correctly get 0 results when running this:

```
select 
    enc_id
  , sum(c.amt3) as sumAmt3
from Charge c
where c.enc_id = 1
group by c.enc_id
having sum(c.amt1 + c.amt2) = 0.00;
```

Another option is removing unwanted `enc_id` from the aggregation query with [**`not exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
select 
    c.enc_id
  , sum(c.amt3) as sumAmt3
from Charge c
where c.enc_id = '01'
  and not exists (
    select 1 
    from Charge i
    where i.enc_id = c.end_id
      and (i.amt1>0 or i.amt2>0)
    )
group by c.enc_id;
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/NFBKA57470